# Git - what stash command does?

Tags: git, git-stash

In which scenario stash command should be used ? 
1) Let's assume i have a branch(b1) and there is a file(f1) that i haven't staged. When i create a new branch(b2) from branch(b1), my file(f1) wouldn't be available in the new branch(b2). 

2)But if i had staged file(f1) in branch(b1) then file(f1) would be available in the new branch(b2) because the file(f1) isn't commited yet. This should not happen and that is why we use stash command? 
Please correct me if this is wrong and provide additional informations related to stash

Comment: Your question is too vague for a formal answer, but `git stash` actually applies to _both_ of your examples.  For unstaged (dirty) files, stash makes a commit, and _also_ for staged files stash makes a second commit.  The general use case of `git stash` is that you need to change branches, but you don't want to clean things up and make a formal commit.

Comment: saves ur work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my opinion, the most "classic" scenario for stash usage:

- you work on branch Bug-X
- the fix is not done, but you should resolve very urgent Bug-Y
- you stash your changes for "Bug-X"
- checkout Bug-Y, fix, commit, push
- checkout Bug-X
- unstash and continue to work

Comment: is Bug-Y a new branch created from Bug-X?

Comment: Not necessary. It may be a branch created from any point in history. Stash command create "temporary" commit, so you can switch to any branch

Comment: i accepted your answer after 6 years, i apologize for the delay :). 

6 years passed like nothing. personally i feel like i have improved a little bit but not at a very good rate which would make me feel better about myself

Answer (score 0):

`git stash` will store you working directory
checkout your branch
`git pop` will apply your working directory to this checked out branch
if f1 is the only not staged file it will pop up as it was before you stashed